# Simple jQuery paywall with SetTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently working on a very simple version of a paywall, which basically enables a user to watch a video for a specific amount of time before hiding the video and displaying the paywall. Once registered through a form, one can watch the video without getting interfered with the feature.

Here is my toy example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".video").show();
    $(".paywall").hide();
    var reg = false;
    $(".video").click(function(){
        if (reg == true) {
            var credit = true;
        } else {
            paywall();
        }
    }); 

    $(".form").click(function(){
        register();
        alert("You have been registered");
    });
 });


function paywall(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".video").hide();
        $(".paywall").show();
        var credit = false;
    }, 2000);
}

function register(){
    var reg = true;
    $(".video").show();
    $(".paywall").hide();
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="video">Video Player</div>
<div class="paywall">PAYWALL</div>

<hr>
<div class="form">Form</div>

</body>
</html>
```

However, it seems that I messed smth. up with the `var reg`, so that the paywall gets triggered with any click even though somebody already signed up.

Comment: please confirm the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fixed code as per the mentioned issue. There is an issue in logic.

**if (!reg) -> already registered so need to show wall now)**

I believe it is the answer for mentioned issue and it fulfils his question but without any reason why downvoted

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".video").show();
    $(".paywall").hide();
    var reg = false;
    var credit = false;
    $(".video").click(function(){
        if (!reg)
            credit = true;
        else 
            paywall();        
    }); 
    $(".form").click(function(){
        register();
        alert("You have been registered");
    });
    function paywall(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".video").hide();
            $(".paywall").show();
            credit = false;
         }, 2000);
    }
    function register(){
        reg = true;
        $(".video").show();
        $(".paywall").hide();
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="video">Video Player</div>
<div class="paywall">PAYWALL</div>

<hr>
<div class="form">Form</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @nic Please confirm, whatever I corrected is solved your problem or not?

Comment: any reason for downvote? It is working as per the mentioned requirement. there is an issue in logic. It is the answer for mentioned issue and it fulfils his question but without any reason why downvoted

Comment: The error in OPs code was not *directly* caused by logic - it was caused by scope.  Setting `var reg = true` would not set the same variable as `if (reg)`.  You've inadvertently fixed this in your sample, but not explained that was the underlying problem.  There may *also* be a logic error, but it was not OPs issue.

Comment: Noted. Thanks @freedomn-m. Hereafter I do the clear explanation. I saw the logic mistake then fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the scope of the variables, specifically the on in `register()` is only declared and only available *within* `register()`.

Rather than use global variables, you can move your function inside the doc.ready and use the variables declared in doc.ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".video").show();
    $(".paywall").hide();
    var reg = false;
    var credit = false;

    $(".video").click(function(){
        if (reg == true) {
           credit = true;
        } else {
            paywall();
        }
    }); 

    $(".form").click(function(){
        register();
        alert("You have been registered");
    });

    function paywall(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".video").hide();
            $(".paywall").show();
            credit = false;
        }, 2000);
    }

    function register(){
        // no `var` here, use the one declared above
        reg = true;
        $(".video").show();
        $(".paywall").hide();
    }
 });
```

same for 'credit'.

Comment: thank you very much! I assumed that it was something simple like that.